# Sort or display php array values as a bell curve

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Just throwing this out there if anyone can find a solution. I have a PHP array and I want to sort it so the lower values are at the beginning and end and the higher values are in the middle, with the highest value being dead center (if count of values is odd of course), sort of like a bell curve...

Comment: How does it decide which side the lower values go?  What is your end goal?

Comment: It doest matter what side the lowest value starts. Basically If I have an array like: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7. I want it sorted like: 1,3,5,7,6,4,2

Comment: Could you provide a sample array of values?

Comment: [1]=>10 [2] = 20 [3] => 30 [4] => 40 [5] => 50 SHOULD BE [1]=>10 [3] => 30  [5] => 50  [4] => 40 [2] = 20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

First sort the array of values. `sort()` will reindex the array.

```
sort($values);
```

Separate alternating array elements into two halves based on the index mod 2.

```
foreach ($values as $i => $x) {
    $sides[$i % 2][] = $x;
}
```

<sub>(well, not exactly halves if the array count is odd)</sub>

Form the result by merging one half with the reverse of the other half.

```
$result = array_merge($sides[0], array_reverse($sides[1]));
```

Comment: @AndrewBrown Thanks!